# Two players with two piles of weights remove weights from each pile in their turn

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Player one has weights 2,4,6,8,…,2022 in a pile. Player two has weights 1,3,5,7,…,2021. Player 1 starts the game and remove weights from her pile, one by one (in any order she likes),until her pile weighs less than the second pile. Then player two remove weights until her pile weighs less than of player 1. The winner is the first to take the last weight of her pile. Who has a winning strategy?

We can write the total weight for player one as N^2+N and for player two as N^2 where N=1011. Then at the first turn player 1 can take at most 32 weights and after that player 2 can take at most 6 weights but I'm not sure how to continue. For the simple cases of a small pile it seems that player 1 has a winning strategy.

Comment: Where is this from?

Comment: Interesting game (+1) Have you analyzed it with smaller piles , like $2,4,6$ versus $1,3,5$ ?

Comment: Between this and [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4400126/winning-strategy-for-1001-pile-of-stones) it looks like you are posting current contest problems here for us to solve for you.

Comment: I've tried for smaller piles and it seems to be that player 1 has a winning strategy.